# jquery dialog in IE not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I cannot get a modal dialog to render in IE. The screen goes dark (as in disabled) but the dialog itself is nowhere to be found. Behavior in Chrome is as expected; screen goes dark AND dialog appears. I have repeatedly cleared cache in IE and Chrome to confirm that this is not some sort of stale reference problem.

I also played games with .hide().show() and  $("#waiting1").dialog('open') but with the same results.

```
<html>
   <head>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" >

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function () {      

                    $("#waiting1").dialog();

                });

           </script>
    </head>
    <body>
           <div id="waiting1" style="display:none;">
               <center>
                    <img src="black_loading.gif" />
               </center>
           </div>


     </body>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to `jquery.ui.all.css` has no closing.

If it is running in Chrome and other browsers, it should also be running properly in IE(maybe little differences in the UI).

Comment: I closed the reference to jquery.ui.all.css as edit to OP. I agree - it should run properly in IE, but it does not. I see numerous similarly-flavored posts about modal dialogs behaving a little differently in IE, but none showing behavioral differences as dramatic as completely missing like mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have an issue with your theme or CSS that overrides it. This fiddle approximates your scenario, and it works in IE8 and 10: http://jsfiddle.net/yrFWJ/2/

```
<span class="click">Click</span>

<div id="waiting1" style="display: none;">
  <center>Nice!</center>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

$('.click').click(function() {
  $("#waiting1").dialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and noticed that stylesheets included after jquery.ui.all seemed to be ignored. Explanation: IE limits the number of stylesheets and imports into the stylesheets (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161).

Answer (score 0):

Your example code does not seem to match your description. For example, I do not see you defining the dialog as a modal. Anyway, in the example that you gave you have set the display of your `div` to be hidden in the style attribute. You should not need to do that.  Let the jQuery UI handle the display formatting for you.

You have this:

```
       <div id="waiting1" style="display:none;">
           <center>
                <img src="black_loading.gif" />
           </center>
       </div>
```

Try changing it to this:

```
       <div id="waiting1">
           <center>
                <img src="black_loading.gif" />
           </center>
       </div>
```